# Linear Maps between general vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus, numerical-linear-algebra

[image]

Hello I was wondering if anyone could give me confirmation that what I am doing is correct here.

For part a) I have used the fact that addition in linear maps can be split from a singular bracket and made into multiple sums.

So I have wrote out that:

T(x^2 - 2x - 1)= T(x^2) - T(2x) - T(1)

And used the fact that scalars can be brought outside the bracket:

= T(x^2) - 2*T(x) - T(1)

And subbed in the conditions given above the question and got the answer:

= 3x^2 - 5x - 1

Is this correct?

Comment: The method is absolutely correct ! But be careful, some steps are incorrect (the $+T(1)$ suddenly became $-T(1)$...)

Comment: Ah thank you! That was me being sloppy!